# How to show that $(\xi\eta-\eta\xi)|A\rangle = 0$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

On page 49 of of Dirac's book, *The Principles of Quantum Mechanics*, he states

> A state may be simultaneously an eigenstate of two observables. If the state corresponds to the ket vector $|A|\rangle$ and the observables are $\xi$ and $\eta$, we should then have the equations
>
> $$\xi|A\rangle = \xi'| A\rangle$$
>   $$\eta|A\rangle = \eta'| A\rangle$$
>
> where $\xi'$ and $\eta'$ are eigenvalues of $\xi$ and $\eta$ respectively. We can now deduce
>
> $$\xi\eta|A\rangle=\xi\eta'|A\rangle=\xi'\eta'|A\rangle=\xi'\eta|A\rangle=\eta\xi'|A\rangle=\eta\xi|A\rangle$$
>
> or $$(\xi\eta-\eta\xi)|A\rangle = 0$$

To me, a more logical proof for the observables commuting in this case would be:

$$\xi\eta|A\rangle=\xi\eta'|A\rangle=\xi'\eta'|A\rangle=\eta'\xi'|A\rangle=\eta'\xi|A\rangle=\eta\xi|A\rangle$$

What's wrong with these steps compared to Dirac's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go through Dirac's proof. He acts on the ket with both operators,

$$\xi\eta\rvert A \rangle = \xi \eta'\lvert A \rangle$$

and we pick up the eigenvalue of $\eta$. Since it is a constant, we just ignore it now, and let the next operator act on the ket, extracting its eigenvalue:

$$=\xi'\eta' \lvert A \rangle$$

Now substitute $\eta'\lvert A \rangle = \eta \lvert A \rangle$, obtaining,

$$= \xi'\eta \lvert A \rangle$$

We can move the constant $\xi'$ onto the ket, and now substitute $\xi'\lvert A \rangle = \xi \lvert A \rangle$ similarly,

$$= \eta \xi \lvert A \rangle$$

from which we deduce $[\xi,\eta]\lvert A \rangle = 0$. The issue, as David first pointed out, is in your proof, you write,

$$\eta' (\xi|A\rangle)=\eta(\xi|A\rangle)$$

and you are assuming $\eta'$ is an eigenvalue of $\xi|A\rangle$, for the operator $\eta$.